# MongoDB Check if a document/record exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Im trying to use .find({}) with mongogb and unfortunately its not giving me the response I was expecting, I'm unsure how to check if the document exists or not? What I'm trying to do is say:

If a document does exist then do something.. IE send a response back 
but If a document doesn't exist then create the document,

unfortunately I know that a document doesnt exist yet it must be picking up the wrong thing with 'if (docs)' but then when I change it to something else then it always creates records!?

The code:

```
addRefund : (refundCalc, callback) => {
    order_number = refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number;
    dbconnect.createConnection()
    refund.find({order_number: order_number}, (err, docs) => {
        if (docs) {
            console.log('docss!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + JSON.stringify(docs));
            console.log('calling within error!!!!!!')
            let notStored = {"refundDocStored" : "False"}
            callback(notStored)
            dbconnect.closeConnection();
        }
        else {
            refund.create(refundCalc).then((refunddoc) => {
               let filestored = {"refundDocStored" : "True"}                              
               dbconnect.closeConnection();
               callback(filestored)
            }).catch((err)=> {
                console.log(err);
                dbconnect.closeConnection();
            })
        }
    })
},
```

the schema:

```
const refundSchema = new Schema({
domain : { type: String},
refundDetails : {
    customer_details : [],
    refund : {
        shipping : {
            amount : { type: Number},
            tax : {type : Number},
            maximum_refundable : {type : Number}
        },
        refund_line_items: [],
        transactions: []   
    }
}
```

});

The orders are stored within the refundDetails like this:

```
"refundDetails":{"customer_details":{"order":{"order_number":1021
```

It simply doesnt seem to work for me! if a document exists i cant seem to actually prove that it does?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong search query. You are searching for order_number which is a property of an object inside another object. You have to reference the order_number full path in your query i.e `{"refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number" : order_number}`

```
addRefund : (refundCalc, callback) => {
    order_number = refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number;
    dbconnect.createConnection()
    refund.find({"refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number": order_number}, (err, docs) => {
        if (docs) {
            console.log('docss!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + JSON.stringify(docs));
            console.log('calling within error!!!!!!')
            let notStored = {"refundDocStored" : "False"}
            callback(notStored)
            dbconnect.closeConnection();
        }
        else {
            refund.create(refundCalc).then((refunddoc) => {
               let filestored = {"refundDocStored" : "True"}                              
               dbconnect.closeConnection();
               callback(filestored)
            }).catch((err)=> {
                console.log(err);
                dbconnect.closeConnection();
            })
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: The data saves fine, it's just checking if it exists or not

Comment: Okay, I have realized the problem is with the search query used. Use this instead `{"refundCalc.refundDetails.customer_details.order.order_number" : order_number}`